# How do I place a HTML content in a text box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am passing a json object from controller to view which contains `html` content. I need to place this content in a text box.

```
$("#t").attr("value", res);
```

I tried in the above way but the content is not getting placed.Here `#t` is `textbox id`.And i even tried the below method but no luck

```
$("#t").val($(this).html());
```

Could any one please provide me sample or example on how to place content into text box area dynamically

Comment: We need a little bit more information, can you show us some more of the relevant javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="my_txt" />
```

Assuming you have included the jQuery library file, you can set the value of the input like so:

```
$("#my_txt").val("This is now the value");
```

If you are working with some returned JSON, you could simply dump it into the input like so:

```
var returned_json;
$("#my_txt").val(returned_json);
```

Comment: I tried this way...In my text box it is showing some scripting language code rather than the actual content. In the below way....                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/-style:normal;font-variant:normal;">Creating Word 2010 format document!</span></p></div></body></html>

Comment: Could you post an example of what "scripting language code" you are seeing?

Comment: I have posted above...actually it is containing so many lines..in the comment it is not accepting..i have pasted few lines

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/… Word 2010 format document!</span></p></div></body></html>

Comment: This does not look like you are getting JSON back. I would check the URL you are querying for this data. JSON should look like this: http://json.org/example.html

Comment: I am returning dynamic json object.The object contains data of a word doc coming from DB.